# Using Datastax Java Driver to query a row as a JSON

Tags: java, json, scala, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to use the datastax java driver and retrieve the row as a JSON.

I do the classic
`SELECT JSON * from myTable WHERE id=1` and this returns a Json formatted string on CQL.

e.g `{ "uuid" : "12324567-...." }`

This works.

Now when, I try to do the same use the Java driver, I use (in scala)

```
val resultSet = session.execute(queryString)
```

I pick up one row from this result set using: `"resultSet.one()"`. 
This has the string I need, but how do I pick this up?

Experiment: `resultSet.one().getColumnDefinitions.toString`

Prints: `Columns[ [json] (varchar) ]`

Experiment: `resultSet.one().toString()`

Prints: `Row[{"uuid": "3ce19e07-2280-4b31-9475-992bda608e70"}]` <- String I need

How do I pick up a simple string that represents the JSON in my program, without trying to split the strings above ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the the [Cassandra documentation](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-2-json-support):

> The results for `SELECT JSON` will only include a single column named `[json]`. This column will contain the same JSON-encoded map representation of a row that is used for `INSERT JSON`.

In order to access the JSON value of the returned row, you need to use one of the `getString` methods defined on the [`Row`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/core/Row.html) class to get the value of this column either by index or by name:

```
Row row = resultSet.one();
String json1 = row.getString(0);
String json2 = row.getString("[json]");
```

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I should have read the docs better. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @andersschuller isit possible for it to return multiple rows?

Comment: @FlyingAtom A `ResultSet` is an `Iterable<Row>`, so you can simply iterate over it instead of calling `one()`. Alternatively you can call `all()` to get a `List<Row>` containing all the rows.