# Export Cassandra JSON Output to file from C#

Tags: c#, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and i'm trying to execute a select statement from c# using the Cassandra/CSharp driver. I want to export the entire set of results in JSON to a file using SELECT JSON. My only issue is how I should approach writing to a file in C#. Is there a way I can convert a RowSet to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by deriving a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34536342/6952495). The key is that:

> The results for SELECT JSON will only include a single column named [json].

You can use something like this is C#:

```
RowSet rows = session.Execute("select json * from  customer_orders where customerid='1'");
foreach (var row in rows) {
  Console.WriteLine(row.GetValue<String>("[json]"));
}
```

Comment: there are some problems with `select json`. 1) you have no control for formatting, like, format for dates/timestamps is hardcoded in Cassandra. 2) the network consumption is much higher compared to the getting the result set & use built-in JSON formatting locally

Answer (score -1):

You can use  "select json * from table_name..." something like:

```
 RowSet rows = session.Execute("select json * from  customer_orders where customerid='1'");
foreach(Row row in rows)
            Console.WriteLine(row);
```

Each returned row is on JSON format and you can save them into a file to export.

[See official documentation from DATASTAX](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryJSON.html)

Comment: This is returning `Cassandra.Row` for me