# Using datastax driver, how can I read a non-primitive column as a JSON string?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have several non-primitive columns in my cassandra tables.
Some of them are user-defined-types UDTs.

While querying them through datastax driver, I want to convert such UDTs into JSON values.
More specifically, I want to get JSON string for the value object below:

```
        Row row = itr.next();
        ColumnDefinitions cds = row.getColumnDefinitions();
        cds.asList().forEach((ColumnDefinitions.Definition cd) -> {
            String name = cd.getName();
            Object value = row.getObject(name);
      }
```

I have gone through http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/custom_codecs/

But I do not want to add a codec for every UDT I have.

Looking at [Using Datastax Java Driver to query a row as a JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521108/using-datastax-java-driver-to-query-a-row-as-a-json), I tried this too:

```
row.getString(name)
```

But it gives me an error: `Codec not found for requested operation: [set<date> <-> java.lang.String]`

Can the driver somehow return me direct JSON without explicit meddling with codecs and all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use toJson method**

> Starting with version 2.2 of Apache Cassandra™, toJson method return json representation of an object.

Example :

```
CREATE TYPE fullname (
    firstname text,
    lastname text
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    direct_reports set<frozen<fullname>>,
    name frozen<fullname>
);
```

Now you can select direct_reports and name as json

```
SELECT id,toJson(direct_reports) as direct_reports,toJson(name) as name FROM users ;
```

Here i have rename `toJson(direct_reports)` as `direct_reports` and `toJson(name)` as `name` so you can use `row.getString("direct_reports")` and `row.getString("name")` to get the direct_reports json and name json.

Output :

```
 id                  | 62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204
 direct_reports      | [{"firstname": "Naoko", "lastname": "Murai"}, {"firstname": "Sompom", "lastname": "Peh"}]
 name                | {"firstname": "Marie-Claude", "lastname": "Josset"}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashraful, this is helpful. Any idea if we can do this through the datastax driver too? I ask because we **have to** run "Select *" query and cannot add toJson() method in that query.

Comment: you can use select json * from users;

Comment: superb! Thank you so much!